# 'NoneType' object is not callable Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a simple function that takes in a DataFrame object and strips the columns of certain characters:

```
 def tidy_columns(self):
      self.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
      if '_' in self.columns[-1]:
        self.columns.str.replace('_', '')
    elif '?' in df.columns:
        self.columns.str.replace('?', '')
```

However, when I call the function in the main() function like this:

```
df.tidy_columns()
```

I recieve an error that says:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object not callable.
```

It's perplexing because I have other functions in my program that are formatted similarly and I receive no errors.

Comment: Do you need `self.columns = self.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need assign back repalaced columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ss ds', 'ss?aa', 'as sa'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ss ds, ss?aa, as sa]
Index: []

#replace first value of string by empty space and all another values by `_`
df.columns = (df.columns[:1].str.replace(' ', '').tolist() + 
              df.columns[1:].str.replace(' ', '_').tolist())
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('?', '')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ssds, ssaa, as_sa]
Index: []
```

So your function should by changed:

```
def tidy_columns(self):

    self.columns = (self.columns[:1].str.replace(' ', '').tolist() + 
                    self.columns[1:].str.replace(' ', '_').tolist())
    self.columns = self.columns.str.replace('?', '')
    return self.columns
```